# how to scan a string in C without arrays

Tags: c, double, decimal

we got a project in C and in the project we have get a decimal (positive or negative) number and to print the all digits.The explanation page says that the progtam may get a number that is not a double so "we cant use double" and we can not use arrays. Its says that "we have to be creative". This is what I did:

```
For(I=0;I<=2;I++){ Scanf("%d", &a); printf("%d", a);}
```

So if I get "12.3456"(in the same line) as an input its print only the first 3 digits(123). How do I print all the digits for any input.
or you might have different idea... thanks

Comment: Use pointers. I guess it is the purpose of the exercise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int n1, n2, i1,i2;
int status;

status = scanf("%d.%n%d%n", &n1, &i1, &n2, &i2);
if(status == 2)
    printf("%d%0*d\n", n1, i2-i1, n2);
else if(status == 1)
    printf("%d\n", n1);
```

Comment: @ggguhuy Results when the negative is not shown clearly. use `abs` for `n1` ?

Comment: I dont really understand what you did. Can you explain the code?

Comment: @ggguhuy Show an example of the results to be expected in the case of a negative number. "it does not work"  it is not clear what is the problem.